# How to evaluate such sum?

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Let $\mathcal{Q}\sim \mathcal{B}(n,\theta)$, where $n=200$, $\theta=\frac34$. I need to evaluate $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{Q}\geq 160)$ and I have a little problem with that.
$\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{Q}\geq 160)=1-\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{Q}<160)=1-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{159}\binom{200}{k}(\frac34)^k(\frac14)^{200-k}=1-(\frac{1}{4})^{200}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{159}\binom{200}{k}(\frac34)^k 4^{k}=1-(\frac{1}{4})^{200}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{159}\binom{200}{k}3^k=\ldots.$ 
There is an obstacle for me with ending the calculations. I would be grateful if someone could give me some advice.

Comment: I believe you can Central Limit Theorem and approximate the result with normal distribution.

Comment: Could you write about it more in answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [this result here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation), $\mathcal B(n,\theta)$ can be approximated as $\mathcal N (n\theta, n\theta (1-\theta)) $.

For your case, we have

$$\mathbb P(\mathcal Q \ge 160) \approx \mathbb P\left(\mathcal Q^* \ge \frac {X-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=\mathbb P\left(\mathcal Q^*\ge\frac {160-150}{\sqrt{37.5}}\right)\approx \mathbb P(\mathcal Q^*\ge1.6323)$$
and we check the tables for this $Z$-value. Should be around $0.05$.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: I find [Stat Trek](https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx) useful for double-checking answers. They've got $0.057$.

Comment: Thanks to normal approximation I obtained $0.05155$ so roughly $0.052$. Seems to be reasonable.